# How to set permission so user can modify a web part but cannot delete it or access site settings or lists?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have a demo page for a web part, so I want a permission level where user can modify web parts using tool part but cannot delete it so other users will also be able to see it. And I also don't want them to access site settings and contents.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to create target audience rules and compile them. As the rules may either ON security group membership or user profile property values.

In order to learn more check the Overview section in the following link :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293